# Sorting pivottable.js rows by total

Tags: pivottable.js

I am fairly new to javascript, so I am sorry if this is an obvious question. I have pivottable.js up and running, but I can't figure out how to order the rows so that they are listed in order of the value of the total column. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you been able to get a solution on this? I too have same problem